# Can't successfully provide dependency using Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm new to Hilt.
I want to provide `DataRepository` for `ViewModel`. My code in `AppModule` is:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDataRepository(): DataRepository {
        return DataRepository()
    }
}
```

And then I want to inject it to the constructor of ViewModel like `private val dataRepository: DataRepository` but I'm getting `No value passed for parameter 'FeaturesApi'` because `FeaturesApi` is dependecy of `DataRepository`. What I want to do is just simply inject dependency without passing any values. How can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

Before using **Hilt** you should really try and understand how **Dagger** works. Since, Hilt is built on top of Dagger!

So, Dagger requires you to provide a dependency graph. Which means for each `class` which is injectable (using Dagger or Hilt) you must also provide a way for Dagger to create instances of its dependencies as well.

Considering the scenario posted in the OP. We have,

```
class DataViewModel(val dataRepository: DataRepository): ViewModel() {
}
```

&

```
class DataRepository(val featuresApi: FeaturesApi) {
}
```

As you have pointed out yourself `featuresApi` is a dependency of `DataRepository` and Dagger has no way of knowing how to create `FeaturesApi` object.

Now, Dagger provides three ways for you to tell it, how to create an instance of any class/type.

1. **`@Inject`**

You can use `@Inject` annotation on a constructor of a `class` defined in your own code to tell Dagger how to create that object. Like so:

```
class DataRepository: @Inject constructor(
    private val featuresApi: FeaturesApi
)
```

Which will act similar to:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDataRepository(): DataRepository {
        return DataRepository()
    }
}
```

Note that there must only be a singular `@Inject` annotated constructor in any given `class`, since providing multiple `@Inject` annotated constructors will confuse Dagger on which constructor to use.

2. **`@Provides`**

You are already familiar with this annotation which can be used in a `@Module` annotated `class`.

This annotation is usually reserved to provide Dagger a way to create instances of classes/types which are not editable for you (Usually library classes or objects created by a library). Which in this case will be, assuming your `FeaturesApi` object is created by `Retrofit` (which is the most popular networking library in Android).

So, by rewriting your `AppModule` class a bit:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideFeaturesApi(retrofit: Retrofit): FeaturesApi {
        return retrofit.create(FeaturesApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

And now Dagger knows how to create a features `FeaturesApi` object.

Note: At this point in your code you'd notice that you've now introduced a dependency for `FeaturesApi` i.e. `Retrofit`. So, now you must also provide a way for Dagger to know how to create `Retrofit` instance. Otherwise Dagger will throw a similar error to `No value passed for parameter 'Retrofit'`.

I'm leaving out the third way for you to figure out and study since that is not related to this question.

---

Further Notes:

- These annotations (with the exception of `@InstallIn`) are in no way related to **Hilt** but are infact used by **Dagger**.
- Also note that the better approach to access lower level objects (in this case `DataRepository`) is through an `interface`.